# Cython and Python class coexistence in ipython?

Tags: python, ipython, cython, jupyter

What is the best approach to have the same classes coexist in ipython environment.

I want to gradually migrate some classes in hierarchy (starting from the root classes) from Python to Cython.
I want to be able to have both versions running (in ipython env), so I can compare performance, and be able to fall-back when needed.

Is there some other approach that may work even if not exactly the way I want.

For my current experiments I started with renaming the classes and importing them separately.
F.e. :

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
from blah import *
from c_blah import *
b = Blah()
cb = c_Blah()

%timeit -n 1000 b.op()
%timeit -n 1000 cb.op()
```

that is cumbersome because I had to rename all class-attr/method accesses.
Also this does not solve my dilemma once I go down the hierarchy.

Any other ideas how to approach this ?
I mean incremental recoding in Cython.

---

cswiercz makes good point :

```
from blah import Blah
from cblah import Blah as cBlah
```

this is OK, but supporting hierarchy will require modifications.
Will keep it open for other ideas.

Comment: Why are you using `import *`? Stop doing that, and your problem goes away instantly.

Comment: I use one class per file normally.. so it wont matter

Comment: "I use one class per file normally" - also a bad idea. This isn't Java here. You don't always need classes, and when you do, there's no reason to limit yourself to one per file.

Comment: @user1019129 Can you clarify what you mean by "hierarchy"? Are you referring to, say, module A importing from module B and your plan to eventually Cythonize both?

Comment: Also, adding to @user2357112 's comment, why you can't create an "implementation zoo" within a single Cython module? You can keep the original Python implementation in there as "BlahPython" and add other implementations (e.g. "BlahCython", "BlahMemoryViews") as you go in a sort of strategy design pattern. Once you determine the "best" version you can set a default via `Blah = BlahMemoryViews` so when the user imports `Blah` they end up using the desired implementation.

Comment: @chris yes, A -> B -> C ... i start with cythonizing A, then B then C

Comment: Any update on your progress? I'm interested to hear your solution since I write a lot of Cython, myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `import x as y` method for renaming definitions within modules. For example, if `foo.py` contains a function `func` and `bar.pyx` also contains the function `func` (perhaps this is you trying to write a Cython version of `foo.func()`) then you can do the following in your timing script:

```
# separate imports
from foo import func as func_py
from bar import func as func_cy

# use the code
func_py(2.0)
func_cy(2.0)
```

This way you can keep a meaningful naming scheme within the `foo` and `bar` modules.